# getBbox is not a function in AfterViewInit

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm currently facing a problem in one of my Angular component default test who only render the comp.

I'm getting the error "getBbox is not a function" but only in my test, not in browser execution... I don't understand why....

Here's the template **hint.html**

```
<svg:g #rootElement [attr.transform]='translate'>
  <text lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" preserveAspectRatio=" xMidYMid slice" data-name="Hint">
    <tspan>
      {{dimension1}} {{spliter}} {{dimension2}}
    </tspan>
  </text>
</svg:g>
```

The ts file of the component :

```
@Component({
  selector: '[node-hint]',
  templateUrl: './hint.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hint.component.css']
})
export class HintComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('rootElement') rootElement: ElementRef;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var element = this.rootElement.nativeElement as SVGGraphicsElement;
    this.componentWidth = element.getBBox().width;
    this.callSomeMethod();
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.callSomeMethod();
  }

  callSomeMethod(){}
}
```

And here's the default test who fail :

```
describe('HintComponent', () => {
  let component: HintComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HintComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HintComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HintComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {});

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

In others lifecycle methods as ngAfterViewChecked there's no error but I need my component width before the content is initialized !

**How could i fix this error ?**
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you get rid of the `async` in the first `beforeEach`? Sometimes timing can be a problem in this kind of unit test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But it doesn't seems to have fixed my issue...